# Blank map in my device - google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps

Im having this problem since hours , i just did everything right, in the dev console i put the sha1 correctly , the package name and everything is enabled

now im getting this in my phone
[image]

but in my emualtor is working...

i thested it in 2 devices, all google play is updated, all permisions are granted in the android manifest

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.usuario.googlemapstest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.usuario.googlemapstest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Reference in android manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

in the values folder is my key

i really dont know why this happends... any idea?

Comment: Show how you reference the api key in the manifest

Comment: @DanielNugent done

Comment: That is inside the application tag?

Comment: @DanielNugent the metadata yes